# Set partitions in Python

Tags: python, arrays, combinatorics

I have an array of `[1,2,3]`

I want to make all the possible combinations using all elements of the array:

Result:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1,2], [3]]
[[1], [2,3]]
[[1,3], [2]]
[[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list?rq=1

Comment: What results would you expect for `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: I think your output for rows #2-#4 should have the single integers as one-element lists or singletons

Comment: Seems to me that this is related to [partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: You are actually looking for [set partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: any reasons why it's `[[1,2],3]` and not `[[1,2],[3]]` but its [[1], [2], [3]] and not `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The question linked has answers returning lists that don't contain all the elements in the original set. This question is different. In fact, the other question is not even that closely related.

Comment: `[[1],[2],[3]], [[1,2],[3]], [[1],[2,3]], [[1,3],[2]], [[1,2,3]]` is not same as what would be wanted on the other question for the same input, which would be `[[], [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3]]`.

Comment: I agree; this question is not a duplicate (of the suggested question, anyhow; there may be another lurking around.)  `itertools.combinations` doesn't yield set partitions.

Comment: Identical to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18353280/3780389) but without the restriction on the number of subsets in the generated partitions.  Still, solutions to either would likely be helpful to both.

Answer (score 73):

Since this nice question has been brought back to life, here's a fresh answer.

The problem is solved recursively: If you already have a partition of *n-1* elements, how do you use it to partition *n* elements? Either place the *n*'th element in one of the existing subsets, or add it as a new, singleton subset. That's all it takes; no `itertools`, no sets, no repeated outputs, and a total of just *n* calls to `partition()`:

```
def partition(collection):
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return

    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        # put `first` in its own subset 
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller


something = list(range(1,5))

for n, p in enumerate(partition(something), 1):
    print(n, sorted(p))
```

Output:

```
1 [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
2 [[1], [2, 3, 4]]
3 [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
4 [[1, 3, 4], [2]]
5 [[1], [2], [3, 4]]
6 [[1, 2, 3], [4]]
7 [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
8 [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
9 [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
10 [[1, 2, 4], [3]]
11 [[1], [2, 4], [3]]
12 [[1, 2], [3], [4]]
13 [[1, 3], [2], [4]]
14 [[1, 4], [2], [3]]
15 [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: I guess this solution is more obvious than I thought :-) (posted the same in the new question that bumped this one)

Comment: Damn! If I'd seen it I could have saved myself the time to work this out... but also missed out on the fun. (But this question was bumped by being edited, I don't see a link to the other one.)

Comment: I agree, this was quite fun. And a good exercise. The new question was temporarily marked as duplicate of this one, that's how this one got the attention and then the edit.

Comment: How did it end up _not_ being a duplicate, though? They are exactly the same.

Comment: This algorithm is due to who?

Comment: @étale-cohomology, I came up with it myself. I'm sure I'm not the first one to.

Comment: Is there any ways of limiting the results to strictly consecutive lists? For example, I would like to remove the results `[[1, 3, 4], [2]]`, `[[1, 4], [2, 3]]`, and so on. Also, is there a way to limit the number of partitions with that answer? As an example, let's say I limit my number of partitions to 3, I would like the algorithm to remove the last set `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]` as it has 4 partitions. I opened a question with the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820190/set-ordered-partitions-in-python-of-maximum-size-n

Comment: I suspect the same approach would work, but it's a different problem; I suggest you formulate it *precisely* and ask a new question (feel free to reference this question, to say explicitly that it's not the same problem).

Comment: This answer is adapted while maintaining efficiency for k-subsets here (in a k-subsets/partitions question where this variation was asked): https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240277/218590

Comment: Thanks for the notification, @GregoryMorse! Amazed to hear that my algorithm is faster than (this particular implementation of) Knuth's, even though it's not specific to the k-subset task. :-)

Comment: Hi @alexis, just FYI, right when you posted this I realized the timing code was totally wrong as I had taken the snippet from the Knuth code which only measured to the first yield and was totally wrong (except it was right for the `t` code it correctly measured as it did not use generators but compiled a list).  Its still more than twice as fast when properly iterating through the generator though :).  I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D thanks for the edit, but I fear it makes it harder to read and validate the algorithm. `first` is the first element, while `[ collection[0] ]` does not have a similarly natural description (and `collection[:1]` even less so.) I don't think avoiding some list-building operations is worth the increase in conceptual complexity.

Comment: No prob - thought about this but to me was actually clearer (it was not performance I was after). I wondered why are we always building a list we just unpacked, it's kind of a reflex. The best of both worlds would be to use python3's unpacking operations as in `[first, * subset]` - faster and clearer and then `first` is ok :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a faster way to do this? beyond N = 13, it's quite slow. I want to skip partitions with subsets of size 1

Comment: The algorithm does not have any real inefficiencies, so I doubt you can improve on it without recoding it to C or something. There are a lot of partitions with N = 13, so it's not surprising it's slow. Excluding partitions with singleton subsets turns this into a different problem -- why don't you ask a new question and explain what you are after. (I'd mention this question so people will not think yours is a duplicate.)

Comment: @alexis here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473074/speed-up-set-partition-generation-by-skipping-ones-with-subsets-smaller-or-large

Comment: Well, good luck!

Answer (score 11):

Unlike my comments suggested, I was unable to quickly find an itertools based relatively fast solution! Edit: this is no longer quite true, I have a fairly short (but slow and unreadable) solution using itertools largely, see the end of the answer. This is what I got instead:

The idea is that we find all the combinations of integers that add up to the length of the list, and then get lists with slices of that length.

E.g. for a list of length 3, the combinations, or partitions, are (3), (2, 1), (1, 2) and (1, 1, 1). So we return the first 3 items of the list; the first 2 and then the next 1; the first 1 then the next 2 and the first 1, then the next 1, then the next 1.

I got code for integer partioning from [here](http://homepages.ed.ac.uk/jkellehe/partitions.php). However, partition functions don't return all permutations of the partitions (i.e. for 3 it would just return (3), (2, 1) and (1, 1, 1). So we need to call `itertools.permutations` on each of the partitions. We then need to remove duplicates - just as `permutations([1, 2, 3])` is `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]`; `permutations([1, 1, 1])` is `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`. An easy way of removing duplicates is by turning each list of tuples into a `set`.

Then all that remains is getting slices of the list the for the lengths in the tuple.
E.g. `f([1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0])` goes to `[[0], [0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]`.

My definition of that is this:

```
def slice_by_lengths(lengths, the_list):
    for length in lengths:
        new = []
        for i in range(length):
            new.append(the_list.pop(0))
        yield new
```

Now we just combine everything:

```
def subgrups(my_list):
    partitions = partition(len(my_list))
    permed = []
    for each_partition in partitions:
        permed.append(set(itertools.permutations(each_partition, len(each_partition))))

    for each_tuple in itertools.chain(*permed):
        yield list(slice_by_lengths(each_tuple, deepcopy(my_list)))

>>> for i in subgrups(my_list):
        print(i)

[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Also, you need to do `import itertools` and `from copy import deepcopy` at the top of the program as well.

Edit: your given output is unclear. I presumed you wanted the function that I have given you, but your output also contains `[[1,3],[2]]`, where the elements in the output are in a different order, unlike the rest of your suggested output (I have taken the liberty of presuming you actually want `[[1, 2], [3]]` not `[[1, 2], 3]`).

That is to say, I presume what you meant to give as output was this:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

If in actual fact it was this:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1], [3], [2]]
[[1], [3, 2]]
[[1, 3], [2]]
[[1, 3, 2]]
[[2], [1], [3]]
[[2], [1, 3]]
[[2, 1], [3]]
[[2, 1, 3]]
[[2], [3], [1]]
[[2], [3, 1]]
[[2, 3], [1]]
[[2, 3, 1]]
[[3], [1], [2]]
[[3], [1, 2]]
[[3, 1], [2]]
[[3, 1, 2]]
[[3], [2], [1]]
[[3], [2, 1]]
[[3, 2], [1]]
[[3, 2, 1]]
```

Then you simply need to call `subgrups` for each 3-length permutation of the original list, e.g. for each permutation in `itertools.permutations(my_list, len(my_list))`.

Edit: Now to hold up to my promise of a short `itertools` based solution. Warning - it may be both unreadable and slow.

First we replace `slice_by_lengths` with this:

```
def sbl(lengths, the_list):
    for index, length in enumerate(lengths):
        total_so_far = sum(lengths[:index])
        yield the_list[total_so_far:total_so_far+length]
```

Then from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036764/2387370) answer we get our integer partitioning function:

```
def partition(number):
    return {(x,) + y for x in range(1, number) for y in partition(number-x)} | {(number,)}
```

This function actually gets all permutations of the integer partitions for us, so we don't need

```
for each_partition in partitions:
    permed.append(set(itertools.permutations(each_partition, len(each_partition))))
```

anymore. However, it is much slower than what we had before, as it is recursive (and we are implementing it in Python).

Then we just put it together:

```
def subgrups(my_list):
    for each_tuple in partition(len(my_list)):
        yield list(slice_by_lengths(each_tuple, deepcopy(my_list)))
```

Or less readable, but without the function definitions:

```
def subgrups(my_list):
    for each_tuple in (lambda p, f=lambda n, g:
                          {(x,) + y for x in range(1, n) for y in g(n-x, g)} | {(n,)}:
                              f(p, f))(len(my_list)):
        yield list(my_list[sum(each_tuple[:index]):sum(each_tuple[:index])+length] for index, length in enumerate(each_tuple))
```

which is a function definition and two lines, so fairly close to what I originally stated (although much less readable and much slower)!

(Functions called `subgrups` because the question originally asked to find "all subgrups")

Answer (score 11):

Consider [`more_itertools.set_partitions`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.set_partitions).

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


lst = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Code**

Flatten a range of `k` set partitions:

```
[part for k in range(1, len(lst) + 1) for part in mit.set_partitions(lst, k)]
```

Output

```
 [((1, 2, 3),),
  ((1,), (2, 3)),
  ((2,), (1, 3)),
  ((3,), (1, 2)),
  ((1,), (2,), (3,))]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party package.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to have it in JS. This indeed took me some time to implement. I was struggled with "Value & Reference" with JS.

Algorithm is the same as @alexis explained above.

Function deepCopy is clone an array, instead of copy to an array.

```
function deepCopy(val){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
}

function partitions(arr) {
    var results = [];

    if (arr.length == 0) {
        results.push([[]]);
        return results;
    }

    if (arr.length == 1) {
        results.push(new Array(arr));
        return results;//[[[1]]]
    }

    var last = arr[arr.length - 1];
    var sub = partitions(arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1));//remove the last item

    //partitions(2) => [ [ [ 's1', 's2' ] ], [ [ 's1' ], [ 's2' ] ] ]
    //val => [ [ 's1', 's2' ] ] or [ [ 's1' ], [ 's2' ] ]
    //set => [ 's1', 's2' ] or [ 's1' ], [ 's2' ]
    sub.map((partition) => {
        //val => each partition
        //1) insert the "last" into each set, together with the rest of sets in the same partition makes a new partition
        partition.map((set) => {
            //set=>each set of one particular partition
            set.push(last);
            results.push(deepCopy(partition));
            set.pop();
        });
        //2), insert the "last" as a singlton set into the partition, make it a new partition
        partition.push([last]);
        results.push(deepCopy(partition));
        partition.pop();
    });

    return results;
}

var arr = ["s1", "s2", "s3"];
const results = partitions(arr);
console.log(results);
```

Outputs:

```
[
  [ [ 's1', 's2', 's3' ] ],
  [ [ 's1', 's2' ], [ 's3' ] ],
  [ [ 's1', 's3' ], [ 's2' ] ],
  [ [ 's1' ], [ 's2', 's3' ] ],
  [ [ 's1' ], [ 's2' ], [ 's3' ] ]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I converted alexis' answer to use loops instead of recursion. The code isn't as easy to understand but should now also work with very large sets:

```py
def partition(collection):
    collection_except_last = reversed(collection[:-1])
    only_last = list(collection[-1:])

    # start with the partition for a 1-element collection and then add elements
    partitions = [[only_last]]
    for element in collection_except_last:
        refined_partitions = []
        for partition_ in partitions:
            # insert `element` in each of the subpartition's subsets
            for n, subset in enumerate(partition_):
                refined = partition_[:n] + [[element] + subset] + partition_[n + 1 :]
                refined_partitions.append(refined)
            # put `element` in its own subset
            refined_partitions.append([[element]] + partition_)
        partitions = refined_partitions
    return partitions
```

Comment: collection: Sequence[T] ?

Comment: I removed those Sequence and List, and it's still slow