# get all the partitions of the set python with itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

How to get all partitions of a set?

For example, I have array `[1, 2, 3]`. I need to get `[[1], [2], [3]], [[1], [2, 3]], [[2], [1,3]], [[3], [1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3]]`.

Now, I wrote this code:

```
def neclusters(S, K):
    for splits in itertools.combinations(range(len(S)), K):
       yield np.split(S, 1 + np.array(splits))
```

But that code don't return `[[2],[1,3]]`.

I could take all permutations of the original set and run this code on them. But can this be made easier?

Comment: `np`.... are you also using _NumPy_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set partitions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python)

Comment: @AlexHall I think that the focus on `itertools` is enough to make this a non-duplicate. Itertools seems like it has the necessary tools but it isn't clear how those tools can be combined to get a good solution for this.

Comment: @JohnColeman The top answer shows how to do it primarily with itertools and also that doing so is a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexHall The top answer doesn't use itertools. The other answer does, but the author of it refers to it as slow. It seems like there is room for improvement. Maybe there isn't, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote this one for fun:

```
def partition(a_list):
    yield [[x] for x in a_list]   
    for i in range(1, len(a_list) + 1):
        _l = a_list[:]
        yield [_l.pop(i-1), _l]
    yield a_list

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print list(partition(my_list))

#or

for p in partition(my_list):
    print p
```

Comment: Your `partition(list(range(4)))` does not generate `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]`. Choose one of the methods from [the thread that Alex Hall linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list()
for l in range(len(a)+1): b.append([c for c in combinations(a, l)])

print(b)
```

check this

Comment: you'r code return [[()], [(1,), (2,), (3,)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)]]