# Finding combinations of a list of numbers – not that "normal" way

Tags: php, math, combinations

I've searched now for more than two days around the web for any working solution. But maybe I just need the right "word" to google for. Let me explain, what I want. Just found lot of articles of combinations and permutations, but they're not covering my requirements (or I don't understand how to do this).

Let's assume, that I'll have a list of numbers: `[1, 2, 3]`

Now, I want all possible combinations of them. 
I need that kind of result (for the given example):

```
1 2 3
1 2+3
1+2+3
2 1+3
3 1+2
```

Those are all available combinations (hope so). I don't need repetition, so `1 2+3` is the same as `1 3+2`.

Is there any Math genius who may help me with it? Is there any formula I can calculate the result count?

Trying to solve it in PHP but it oftens end in endless recursive executions and a memory limit exception.

Comment: Aren't there many more combinations you can have?

Comment: nCr, n choose r, binomial coefficient are all terms that may be related to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to generate **[set partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)**. There is [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) of such partitions (1,2,5,15,52...).

It is not hard ([arbitrary example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140324-00/?p=1413)) to generate partitions recursively (adding n to every part of list of (n-1) partition and to separate part).

But there exist effective iterative ways. For example, the next Delphi code implements [this article](http://www.informatik.uni-ulm.de/ni/Lehre/WS03/DMM/Software/partitions.pdf) *(Efficient Generation of Set Partitions.
Michael Orlov)* approach. (PartitionToString is quite ineffective quick-made routine)

Output

```
1/2/3/4/
1/2/3,4/
1/2,4/3/
1,4/2/3/
1/2,3/4/
1/2,3,4/
1,4/2,3/
1,3/2/4/
1,3/2,4/
1,3,4/2/
1,2/3/4/
1,2/3,4/
1,2,4/3/
1,2,3/4/
1,2,3,4/

  procedure GeneratePlusCombs(n: Integer; List: TStrings);
  var
    K, M: array of Integer;
    i, j: Integer;

    function Prev: Boolean;
    var
       i, j: Integer;
    begin
    Result  := False;
    for i := n - 1 downto 1 do

      if K[i] > K[0] then begin
        K[i] := K[i] - 1;
        M[i] := M[i - 1];
        for j := i + 1 to n - 1 do begin
          M[j] := M[i] + j - i;
          K[j] := M[j];
        end;
        Exit(True);
      end;
    end;

    function PartitionToString: string;
    var
      j, cnt, d: Integer;
      s: string;
    begin
      s := '';
      for j := 0 to n - 1 do begin
        cnt := 0;
        for d := 0 to n - 1 do
          if K[d] = j then begin  ///digit d belongs to j-th part of current partition
            s := s + Format('%d,', [d + 1]);
            cnt := cnt + 1;
          end;
        if cnt > 0 then
          s[Length(s)] := '/';
      end;
      Result := s;

    end;

  begin
    SetLength(K, n);
    SetLength(M, n);

    for i := 0 to n - 1 do begin
      K[i] := i;
      M[i] := i;
    end;

    List.Add(PartitionToString);
    while Prev do
      List.Add(PartitionToString);

  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That helped me a lot, especially the keywords "set variation". I did not success converting the given delphi code to PHP, but I found a python script, which does something similar.

If anyone is interested, have a look in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comment above, I found a solution for this problem.

A helpful (Python) script is posted in here:
[Set partitions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python)

For those, who need it in PHP, in here my conversion:

```
// recursive function
function partition($collection) {
    if (count($collection) == 1) {
        yield array($collection);
        return;
    }

    $first = $collection[0];

    foreach (partition(array_slice($collection, 1)) as $smaller) {
      foreach ($smaller as $n => $subset) {
        yield array_merge(
            array_slice($smaller, 0, $n),
            array(array_merge(array($first), $subset)),
            array_slice($smaller, $n + 1)
        );
      }

      yield array_merge(array(array($first)), $smaller);
    }
}

// set up an array
$something = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

// loop all the variants
foreach (partition($something) as $n => $p) {
    var_dump($p);
}
```