# Sets: Given a list (of students), how can I generate all sets (of teams) with maximums and minimums?

Tags: python, arrays, set, grouping, combinatorics

I working on some functionality, on behalf of a teacher, that groups students into teams.  To this end, I am looking for help to determine an efficient way of generating all possible team combinations that meet the following criteria:

1. All students are represented in a team, and each student appears only once
2. Teams have a maximum and minimum size
3. There are a maximum number of teams

Example inputs:

```
students=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
max_team_size=5
min_team_size=2
max_team_count=4
```

Example of some desired output:

```
[['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g'],['h','i','j']],
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f','g'],['h','i','j']],
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i','j']],
[['a','b'],['c','d','e'],['f''g','h'],['i','j']],
[['a','b','c','d','e'],['f''g','h','i','j']],
...
```

There are a bunch of other student/teacher preferences and such that will be used to filter
the results later, but for now, need some help generating all possible combinations of teams.
I've tried using `[itertools.combinations`][1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), but I haven't yet found the magic that fits my particular
situation (given my novice python and set theory skills).  I've also come across similar,
over-my-head [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python/30134039#30134039), which get me close, but are not quite what I'm after:

Comment: Are the teams always in order from the original list, or could you also have `[a, h, i, j]`?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Have you managed to break down the problem? Do you have anything to go off of?

Comment: If they can be in any order, there will be too many combinations to list them all.

Comment: order doesn't matter, but obviously I don't want duplicate results

Comment: adjusted variable names as suggested

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me like this is a permutations problem, which itertools can handle.

```
from itertools import permutations

players = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
allPossibleCombos = permutations(players)
```

This will generate all the possible arrangements of the players. The team boundaries could be indicated by the index in the list e.g. Team 1 from index 0 to 3, Team 2 is 4 - 6...etc.

```
TEAM 1                TEAM 2           TEAM 3       
('b', 'h', 'a', 'g', | 'i', 'c', 'e', | 'j', 'f', 'd')

('b', 'h', 'a', 'g', | 'i', 'c', 'f', | 'd', 'e', 'j')

('b', 'h', 'a', 'g', | 'i', 'c', 'f', | 'd', 'j', 'e')
```

As you work through the list and grab a team, you sort it so all the players are in the same order, then you make sure it's unique combination. If it is a unique combo you store it in a dictionary. 
Just an idea. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient method, but you could use the example you linked to above [Set partitions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python/30134039#30134039) or another preferred method to generate all possible combinations of student teams, then have another list where you append only the teams that meet your criteria. Example:

```
def partition(collection):
    # This function was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python/30134039#30134039
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return

    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        # put `first` in its own subset 
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller

student_partitions = []
for n, p in enumerate(partition(Students), 1):
    if len(sorted(p)) <= max_team_count:
        sublist_lengths = [len(x) for x in sorted(p)]
        if all((i <= max_team_size and i >= min_team_size) for i in sublist_lengths):
            student_partitions.append(sorted(p))

for sp in student_partitions:
    print(sp)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I started moving in this direction, but it seems to be prohibitively inefficient.  I'm hoping that someone has a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Student grouping is proved to be an NP-hard problem. Generating all possible team combinations is not quite feasible. From what i can understand, you need all possible team combination for choosing the best, right?
For that, you need an optimization algorithm to optimize your criterion.

In a recent research, a PSO was implemented to classify students under unknown number of groups of 4 to 6. PSO showed improved capabilities compared to GA. I think that all you need is the specific research.

The paper is: Forming automatic groups of learners using particle swarm optimization for applications of differentiated instruction

Perhaps the researchers could guide you through researchgate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338078753

You can find the paper here: https://doi.org/10.1002/cae.22191

I hope I have helped!!