# Reconstruct this generator to yield sorted nested tuples instad of nested lists

Tags: python

I currently have the folliwng generator that yields nested lists (to construt the set of partitions of a set), but i actualy need it to output nested tuples. I currently use a to_tuple hack, but could you help me to make it 'natively' inside the generator ?

```
def _partition(collection):
    #from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python/61141601"
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return
    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in _partition(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        # put `first` in its own subset
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller

def to_tuple(lst):
    return tuple(to_tuple(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in lst)


## using it 
exemple = [0,0,1,4]
pp = [sorted(p) for p in _partition(exemple)]
result = to_tuple(pp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've got:

```py
def _partition(collection):
    # from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python/61141601"
    collection = tuple(collection)
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield (collection,)
        return
    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in _partition(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield tuple(sorted(
                smaller[:n]
                + (tuple(sorted((first,) + subset)),)
                + smaller[n + 1 :]
            ))
        # put `first` in its own subset
        yield tuple(sorted(((first,),) + smaller))
```

With

```py
example = [0, 0, 1, 4]
for p in _partition(example):
    print(p)
```

the output would be:

```py
((0, 0, 1, 4),)
((0,), (0, 1, 4))
((0, 0), (1, 4))
((0,), (0, 1, 4))
((0,), (0,), (1, 4))
((0, 0, 1), (4,))
((0, 1), (0, 4))
((0,), (0, 1), (4,))
((0, 0, 4), (1,))
((0, 1), (0, 4))
((0,), (0, 4), (1,))
((0, 0), (1,), (4,))
((0,), (0, 1), (4,))
((0,), (0, 4), (1,))
((0,), (0,), (1,), (4,))
```

And in unsorted case

```py
example = [2, 0, 1, 4]
for p in _partition(example):
    print(p)
```

it outputs

```py
((0, 1, 2, 4),)
((0, 1, 4), (2,))
((0, 2), (1, 4))
((0,), (1, 2, 4))
((0,), (1, 4), (2,))
((0, 1, 2), (4,))
((0, 1), (2, 4))
((0, 1), (2,), (4,))
((0, 2, 4), (1,))
((0, 4), (1, 2))
((0, 4), (1,), (2,))
((0, 2), (1,), (4,))
((0,), (1, 2), (4,))
((0,), (1,), (2, 4))
((0,), (1,), (2,), (4,))
```

Finally, with repeated elements:

```py
example = [1, 2, 2]
for p in _partition(example):
    print(p)
```

output:

```py
((1, 2, 2),)
((1,), (2, 2))
((1, 2), (2,))
((1, 2), (2,))
((1,), (2,), (2,))
```

To remove the duplicates you can run `set(_partition(example))`

For the sorting on the outer level, I don't think it can be done with generators since we're getting elements one by one and can't compare them before the generator is exhausted.

Comment: It's better. The result is sorted inside each part of each partition, but the partitions themselves are not sorted. for `example = [1,2,2]` i obtain two outputs `((1,2),(2,))` and `((2,),(1,2))`, which i'd like to come as the same. Would it be possible to sort also one level up ? (i dont mean sorting in the outper level, but just reproducing the output of the example i gave up (sorting after the generator). But maybe it's not doable, you are right.

Comment: I still applause what you just did ! Well played.

Comment: Ok, I added another level of sorting. Now to remove duplicates you can just run `set(_partition(example))`. Another option would be to keep track of the seen partitions but I'm not sure how to implement this with recursion.

Comment: And now it's perfect. Indeed, i want to use Counter() and not set(). I did not found the right mathematical logic into these counts, but it will probably be a lot faster if i manage to find one.

Comment: Yes, it's quite complicated maths to compute a number of set partitions