# how to find all the subsets with restrictions in python?

Tags: python, subset, powerset

So i am doing a comb. auction algorithm
and i like to give him N number of items for example

```
(A,B,C)
```

and i want the algorithm to give me back the following result

```
(A,B,C)
(ABC)
(AB,C)
(AC,B)
(BC,A)
```

any ideas ?

i tried this one but its not enough

```
k =[1,2,3]
def powerset(xs):
    result = [[]]
    for x in xs:
        subsets = [subset + [x]  for subset in result]
        result.extend(subsets)
    return result
print (powerset(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partitioning problem that requires recursion. It has been answered here:
[Set partitions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)