# Partition a given list into two or more unordered sets

Tags: python-3.x, partitioning

lst = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7]

I want to partition it into two or more sets.
Here is my code

```
import more_itertools as mit
import pprint as pp
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
x = [part for k in range(1, len(lst) + 1) for part in mit.set_partitions(lst, k)]
x.sort()
x = list(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(x)))
pp.pprint(x)
```

Here is my current output:

```
[[[2], [2], [2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [5], [3, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [3], [2, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [3], [2, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [3], [5], [2, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [3, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [5], [2, 3, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [5], [3, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 3], [2, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 3], [2, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 3], [5], [2, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 3, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 5], [2, 3, 7]],
 [[2], [3], [2, 2, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [3], [2, 2, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [3], [2, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2], [3], [5], [2, 2, 7]],
 [[2], [3, 5], [2, 2, 7]],
 [[2], [5], [2, 2, 3, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2], [5], [3, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [3], [2, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [3], [2, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [3], [5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [3, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [5], [2, 3, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [5], [3, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 3], [2, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 3], [5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 3, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 5], [2, 3, 7]],
 [[2, 3], [2, 2, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 3], [2, 2, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 3], [2, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 3], [5], [2, 2, 7]],
 [[2, 3, 5], [2, 2, 7]],
 [[2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 7]],
 [[3], [2, 2, 2, 5], [7]],
 [[3], [2, 2, 2, 5, 7]],
 [[3], [2, 2, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[3], [2, 5], [2, 2, 7]],
 [[3], [5], [2, 2, 2, 7]],
 [[3, 5], [2, 2, 2, 7]],
 [[5], [2, 2, 2, 3, 7]]]
```

I have managed to remove some amount of redundancy by sorting followed by using `groupby(x)` as you can see but there are more redundancies like

`[[2], [2, 2], [3], [5], [7]]`

and

`[[2, 2], [2], [3], [5], [7]]`

for me are one and the same thing since order is not important to me.

Please dont close the question without putting in an effort. I have framed the question only after going through other similar questions on stackoverflow, they are for [ordered sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python), mine is for unordered sets.(part of my code were formed from those answers)

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to construct a set somehow so that you only have unique combinations in your result(removing all permutations of a list except 1). This can be done by sorting each sublist of the list and then constructing a dictionary.

```
import more_itertools as mit
import pprint as pp
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
lst=[2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
x = [part for k in range(1, len(lst) + 1) for part in mit.set_partitions(lst, k)]
x.sort()
x = list(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(x)))

# sort each sublist
for temp in x:
    temp = temp.sort()

# create a dictionary(hashtable), key of a dictionary should be immutable therefore stringified it
unique_combinations = {str(temp):temp for temp in x}
# since unique keys will have unique values, we have unique combinations here
unique_combinations = list(unique_combinations.values())
pp.pprint(unique_combinations)
```

Output

```
[[[2], [2], [2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2], [3, 7], [5]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 5], [3], [7]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 5, 7], [3]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 7], [3], [5]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 7], [3, 5]],
 [[2], [2], [2, 3, 7], [5]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2], [3, 7], [5]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 3], [2, 5], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 3], [2, 5, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 3], [2, 7], [5]],
 [[2], [2, 3, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2], [2, 3, 7], [2, 5]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 5], [3], [7]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 5, 7], [3]],
 [[2], [2, 5], [2, 7], [3]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 7], [3], [5]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 7], [3, 5]],
 [[2], [2, 2, 3, 7], [5]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 5], [3], [7]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 5, 7], [3]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 7], [3], [5]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 7], [3, 5]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 3, 7], [5]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3, 7], [5]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3], [5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3], [5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 5], [3, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 3], [2, 5], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 3], [2, 7], [5]],
 [[2, 2, 3, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 5], [2, 3, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 5], [2, 3], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 3]],
 [[2, 3], [2, 5], [2, 7]],
 [[2, 2, 7], [2, 3], [5]],
 [[2, 2, 7], [2, 3, 5]],
 [[2, 2, 3, 7], [2, 5]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 5], [3], [7]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 5, 7], [3]],
 [[2, 2, 5], [2, 7], [3]],
 [[2, 2, 7], [2, 5], [3]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 7], [3], [5]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 7], [3, 5]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3, 7], [5]]]
```

Comment: Thanks , it gets the job done. But sorting and hashing multiple time is slowing it down . Maybe the time complexity is increasing a lot . So I was wondering if we could restrict it at the point of generation itself. Here  is the logic of [`set_partitions`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L3184) and corresponding [ticket](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/issues/616). Lets discuss there for further improvements.